# Executing a SAS program in R using system() Command

Tags: r, sas

My company recently converted to SAS and did not buy the SAS SHARE license so I cannot ODBC into the server. I am not a SAS user, but I am writing a program that needs to query data from the server and I want to have my R script call a .sas program to retrieve  the data. I think this is possible using

`df <- system("sas -SYSIN path/to/sas/script.sas")`

but I can't seem to make it work. I have spent all a few hours on the Googles and decided to ask here.

error message:

```
running command 'sas -SYSIN  C:/Desktop/test.sas' had status 127
```

Thanks!

Comment: what does "can't seem to make it work" mean?  what kinds of error messages/failure modes are you getting?

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I added the message I am getting.

Comment: You are very unlikely to get an R dataframe using a command like that.

Comment: don't have time to tackle this right now, but I think the information you need is how to dig in and figure what "status 127" means -- i.e. general troubleshooting tips for `system()`.  Can you run this command in a shell/command window and see if you get more information? There may be arguments to `system()` (maybe `intern`?) that will output more diagnostic/debugging info.  (Maybe status 127 is actually OK, and you're just not getting the output you think ...)

Comment: Thanks again, Ben. I read the documentation for the `system()` and I didn't get much out of it. I will try running it in the shell window and see what results I get.

Comment: cory, I do get a dataframe, but it only has one row equal 127L. Any suggestions other than it won't work?

Comment: Perhaps using keep.log=TRUE and  log.file= option

Comment: @Ben In such situations is it better to give the complete path to the SAS-program `system("<path.to.the.directory>/sas -SYSIN path/to/sas/script.sas")`

Comment: @Ben Is the output from SAS a formatted text string, in which case using some form of `read.table` may be appropriate? I just can't think of a way that this would output an R object with class of data.frame unless you read  in text using read.table

Comment: What does your sas program do? If it generates a table, you could use one of the R packages designed specifically to read sas datasets (Haven for instance). If it generates an external text file (csv, txt...) then use `read.table()` to get the data back into R.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your sas program generates a sas dataset, you'll need to do two things:

1. Through `shell`or `system`, make SAS run the program, but first `cd` in the directory containing the sas executable in case the directory isn't in your PATH environment variable.

   `setwd("c:\\Program Files\\SASHome 9.4\\SASFoundation\\9.4\\")`
   `return.code <- shell("sas.exe -SYSIN c:\\temp\\myprogram.sas")`

   Note that what this returns is NOT the data itself, but the code issued by the OS telling you if the task succeeded or not. A code `0` means task has succeeded.

   In the sas program, all I did was to create a copy of `sashelp.baseball` in the `c:\temp` directory.
2. Import the generated dataset into R using one of the packages written for that. `Haven` is the most recent and IMO most reliable one.

   `# Install Haven from CRAN:`
   `install.packages("haven")`
   `# Import the dataset:`
   `myData <- read_sas("c:\\temps\\baseball.sas7bdat")`

And there you should have it!

Comment: Thanks, Dominic! I appreciate the help.