# How to run sas from R as administrator

Tags: r, cmd, sas, system

I am running SAS from R, but i need administrator pivileges to access a folder. I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681754/run-sas-from-r-using-shell-function.) approach

I tried to set user to adminstrator (with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903629/how-do-i-run-a-program-from-command-prompt-as-a-different-user-and-as-an-admin)), but nothing happens:

```
sas_log <- tempfile()
sas_out <- tempfile()
sas_script <- "mysasscript.sas"
cmd <- sprintf(
  'sas.exe -nosplash -icon -sysin "%s"  -log "%s" -print "%s" -user:Administrator',
  sas_script, sas_log, sas_out
)

return_code  <- system(cmd)  # Runs sas and saves the return code to
```

Comment: Can you fire up R as an admin, and just allow SAS to inherit the permissions?

Comment: No, that doesn't help. This does not give SAS admin rights.

Comment: Another thought: SAS has it's own administration tools. It may be that your access is OK from a windows or linux (whatever you're on) environment, but that your SAS admins may also need to grant access within SAS, e.g. in User Manager area of SAS Management Console.

Comment: Maybe one of the solutions proposed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098101/how-to-open-an-elevated-cmd-using-command-line-for-windows) could work.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. What worked for me is to change the SAS.exe privileges directly in Windows (right-click on icon, properties, etc.). A UAC window does pop up though which is kind of annoying...